# Installing PostGreSql with WiX Installer

Tags: postgresql, installation, wix, embedded-resource

I'm trying to deploy a PostGreSqlServer with my WiX installer but it simply keeps on failing and I don't know why.

The important part of my wxs file:

```
<Binary SourceFile="postgresql-9.2.1-1-windows.exe" Id="PostGreInstaller"  />

<CustomAction  Id="InstallPostGre" BinaryKey="PostGreInstaller"
               ExeCommand='"--serverport 5432 --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount Myadmin --superpassword Mypassword --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended"'
               Execute="deferred" Return="check"   Impersonate="yes" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="InstallPostGre" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Already tried the command in a cmd shell and it worked. Don't why it doesn't in the installer.

I know for sure that the installer has embedded the installer because it has more then 50MB.

I've also started my msi with logging turned on but that didn't really help me either...

```
Action 16:34:29: InstallPostGre. 
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:29:407]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=InstallPostGre,ActionType=1026,Source=BinaryData,Target=--serverport 5432 --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount Myadmin --superpassword Mypassword --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended,)
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:31:698]: Note: 1: 1721 2: InstallPostGre 3: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE410.tmp 4: --serverport 5432 --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount Myadmin --superpassword Mypassword --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended 
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:31:698]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:31:698]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1721 
Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: InstallPostGre, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE410.tmp, command: --serverport 5432 --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount Myadmin --superpassword Mypassword --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended 
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:34:717]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:34:717]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (64:E0) [16:34:34:717]: Product: Hausverwaltung -- Error 1721. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: InstallPostGre, location: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIE410.tmp, command: --serverport 5432 --servicename postgres_service --locale C --superaccount Myadmin --superpassword Mypassword --unattendedmodeui minimal --debuglevel 2 --mode unattended
```

are there any WiX gurus out there? :)

Comment: Please don't distribute installers like this with general purpose applications. The user of the computer may've already installed PostgreSQL, in which case the install will fail. Or they may want to do so in future, and will wonder why none of the instructions they find work - because your program has silent-installed PostgreSQL with your own superuser account and password. It's generally preferable to use the .zip binaries then initdb and create the service account yourself.

Comment: @raphi011 were you able to solve this? :D

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason this is not working is that the postgres exe already contains an msi and you can only install one msi at a time as they create a transaction and (currently I have heard of plans to change this) you can only run one transaction at a time. As the previous answer states you can use a burn bundle to package the two installers together into a seamless user experience. Also you can check in the bundle whether you actually need to install postgres by doing a registry search.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WIX v3.6 Bundle concept to handle this. You can read more about it here http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm

Basically you are packaging your WIX MSI and the EXE into a single WIX bundle package which can be then installed to the target machines.

Or you can write scripts which can be executed via CustomActions, like the EXECCommand you tried. But I would rather use Bundle, because it manages the uninstallation and upgrades in a much better fashion. So try the WIX bundle and see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

I had success with the technique you are using as long as Windows User Access Control was turned off.